# tensorflow2: keras: model.fit() callbacks and eager mode

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am running Tensorflow 2.1 with keras API. I am following the following coding style:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    ...
    model.fit(..., callbacks=callbacks)
```

Now, I would like to save some intermediate layer tensor value as image summary (as a sample what is happening at n-th training step). In order to do this, I've implemented my own callback class. I've also learned how `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` is implemented, since it can save layer weights as image summaries.
I do the following in my `on_epoch_end`:

```
tensor = self.model.get_layer(layer_name).output

with context.eager_mode():
    with ops.init_scope():
        tensor = tf.keras.backend.get_value(tensor)
    tf.summary.image(layer_name, tensor, step=step, max_outputs=1)
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting issue related to eager/graph modes:

```
    tensor = tf.keras.backend.get_value(tensor)
  File "/home/matwey/lab/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3241, in get_value
    return x.numpy()
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Unfortunately, there is a little to no documentation on how to correctly combine keras callbacks and `tf.summary.image`. How could I overcome this issue?

**upd:** tf_nightly-2.2.0.dev20200427 has the same behaviour.

Comment: Can you confirm you get the same error on the nightly build? It's a known bug on TF 2.1 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38038

Comment: Yes, I've just check tf_nightly-2.2.0.dev20200427 and the same issue here.

Comment: Same issue in tf2.4.0 dev nightly build @LukaszTracewski